# Can I add a bounty to another user's question?

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to offer a bounty on an open question someone else posted.  Can I?  If I can't, is it possible to add this feature?  Just upvoting a question is nice too, but sometimes I really want an answer.

Comment: Since bounties are a minimum of 50 points currently, you need at least 50 points of reputation to offer one.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is already possible, but to offer a bounty you need to have enough reputation.

Comment: if you do have enough rep, you'll see a link saying 'start bounty' below the question.